four wheel robot wheels rotate but robot does not move
I am trying to move a four wheeled robot in gazebo using libgazebo_ros_diff_drive plugin.
When i try to publish commands to /cmd_vel the robot's wheels rotate but the robot itself does not move. changing the friction coefficients do not seem to have any effect on movement.
<gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so" >

            <num_wheel_pairs>2</num_wheel_pairs>
            <left_joint>lb_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <left_joint>lf_wheel_joint</left_joint>
            <right_joint>rb_wheel_joint</right_joint>
            <right_joint>rf_wheel_joint</right_joint>
            <wheel_separation>1.2</wheel_separation>
            <wheel_diameter>0.45</wheel_diameter>

            <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>
            <update_rate>50</update_rate>       

            <max_wheel_torque>20000</max_wheel_torque>
            <max_wheel_acceleration>10.0</max_wheel_acceleration>
            
            <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
            <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
        
            <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
            <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
            <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>


        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="lb_wheel">
        <mu1>1.5</mu1>
        <mu2>1.5</mu2>
        <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="lf_wheel">
        <mu1>1.5</mu1>
        <mu2>1.5</mu2>
        <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="rb_wheel">
        <mu1>1.5</mu1>
        <mu2>1.5</mu2>
        <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="rf_wheel">
        <mu1>1.5</mu1>
        <mu2>1.5</mu2>
        <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    </gazebo>

here is the robot's structure:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find robotfw)/urdf/inertial_macros.xacro"/>
<xacro:include filename="$(find robotfw)/urdf/gazebo_control.xacro"/>

    <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1" />
    </material>

    <material name="orange">
        <color rgba="1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
    </material>

    <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
    </material>

    <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
    </material>

    <link name="world" />

    <joint name="virtual_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.825" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="base_link" />


    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="chassis"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0 "/>
    </joint>

    <link name="chassis">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.8 1.2 1.2"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="white"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.8 1.2 1.2"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_box mass="5.0" x="1.8" y="1.2" z="1.2">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_box>
    </link>

    

    <link name="lf_wheel">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>            
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.25" length="0.22" radius="0.225">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <joint name="lf_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis" />
        <child link="lf_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="0.45 0.6 -0.6" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="rf_wheel">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>            
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.25" length="0.22" radius="0.225">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <joint name="rf_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis" />
        <child link="rf_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="0.45 -0.6 -0.6" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="lb_wheel">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>            
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.25" length="0.22" radius="0.225">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <joint name="lb_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis" />
        <child link="lb_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="-0.45 0.6 -0.6" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="rb_wheel">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>            
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.225" length="0.22"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.25" length="0.22" radius="0.225">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>

    <joint name="rb_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis" />
        <child link="rb_wheel" />
        <origin xyz="-0.45 -0.6 -0.6" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

</robot>


